# Did Sebulba's flame weapon have any mechanical effect or was it just cosmetic?

Tags: star-wars-episode-i-racer

In Star Wars Episode One Pod Racer, you have the option of several racers to select.  One of them is Sebulba, who has a flame weapon that fires from the side of the pod if you double-tap one of the bumper controls.

To the best of my memory, Sebulba was the only racer who had the option for a weapon - **did it actually have a mechanical effect on other racers, or was it just there to look good?**

Or did other racers have weapons too, and I never figured out how to utilize them?